# -bash: jupyter: command not found

Tags: python, jupyter

I installed a copy of Anaconda to play around with, but decided I liked Homebrew better, so I removed it. However, this seems to have messed up my install of Jupyter Notebooks, as I can no longer access it. I reinstalled it with `pip install jupyter` and when I run `pip show jupyter` I get:

```
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.
Home-page: http://jupyter.org
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.org
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: ipywidgets, nbconvert, notebook, jupyter-console, qtconsole, ipykernel
```

But when I run `which -a jupyter` I get nothing. I even tried uninstalling and installing python again via Homebrew and it still gives me the error, `-bash: jupyter: command not found`.

I have python installed correctly, `which -a python` gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Any ideas as to why it might not be working?

Comment: Homebrew and Anaconda have very different purposes

Comment: It's possible pip installed the binary somewhere else. What does `find / -name jupyter` return?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm on Mac and am using Zsh. For some reason, after I installed Python3, the following line:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
```

was added to `.zprofile` instead of `.zshrc`.

I transferred the line to `.zshrc` and did `source ~/.zshrc`. That did the trick.

Comment: Thank you for saving my day

Answer (score 4):

The below command seems to install only python files (under */usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages* in your case):

```
pip install jupyter
```

You can run the jupyter as a Python's module like this:

```
python -m jupyter
```

To see all installed modules you can type the following command from the Python's shell:

```
help('modules')
```

As an alternative you can try to upgrade the package:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade jupyter
```

If you want to access the jupyter by simply typing *jupyter* in your shell then the path to the *jupyter's* binary file should be placed inside the *PATH* variable.

During the installation of Anaconda software the *jupyter* binary is placed under */usr/local/bin/jupyter* (Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS Mojave,

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

installs `jupyter` under

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/
```

. Your version may be different from `3.5`. You can then link to the binary there as follows.

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/jupyter /usr/local/bin/
```

In the rare case that `/usr/local/bin/` is not on your `PATH`, you may replace it above with some folder that is.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
python -m notebook
```

should do the trick